# Please help me figure out how this star was made in canvas

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, trigonometry

I found this code online and I'm trying to figure it out.

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 function drawStar(cx, cy, spikes, outerRadius, innerRadius){
  var rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3;
  var x = cx;
  var y = cy;
  var step = Math.PI / spikes;

  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(cx, cy - outerRadius) //100 - 30

  for(i = 0; i < spikes; i++){
   $(".display").append(Math.cos(rot) +" , ")
   x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius;
   y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * outerRadius;
   console.log("x : ", x, " y : ", y)
   ctx.lineTo(x,y);
   rot += step;

   x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
   y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
   ctx.lineTo(x,y);
   rot+= step;
  }

  ctx.lineTo(cx, cy- outerRadius);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
  ctx.stroke()
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,2, 0, (Math.PI * 2), true);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fill()
  ctx.closePath();
 }

 drawStar(75, 100, 5,45, 15) //cx,cy,spikes, outerRadius, innerRadius
}
```

```css
canvas{
 background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<div class="display"></div>
```

I see it says `var rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3` I'm going to figure this to be a 270 deg angle because 90 * 3 = 270. I need help figuring out how they got the point of the top right corner of star. that I believe is the `outerRadius` .

They do `x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius;` for the top right point (trying to get the top right point) is 'rot' in degrees 54? .. i figure `(Math.PI / 5) * 180 / Math.PI` 5 is from the step variable.. that's equal to 36 so I did 90 degrees - 36 to get 54. I hope I'm figuring it out right? I'm not sure why they used 270 degrees. can you elaborate on that? I'm not sure why they used `var rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3` if I play with the nums a little bit I get garbage. I'm assuming they are using that to get the angles the point makes up but It's hard for me to put the pieces together.

Edit: I put the red dot in there at the center to help me gauge the angle of the points to the center.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward though:

- Angles in canvas is calculated like this: 0 degree is at the horizontal, and it goes clockwise, so 1.5 PI (270 deg) is right at the top.

  ```
  cx + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius = 0
  cy + Math.sin(rot) * outerRadius = outerRadius
  ```
- `2 * PI` is the full circle, so to draw each pikes you will draw them every `2 * PI/spikes`. You can see that `rot` is increased two times of `PI/spikes` each, one for the inner point and second is for the outer one.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some text to your demo, hoping it helps answer your question.

First, you are correct at assuming that `Math.PI / 2 * 3` is the same as getting 270 deg in radians. For illustration, I've changed it to `270 * Math.PI / 180` which yields the same result and perhaps is more intuitive to read.

The reason it starts at 270 is because if you think of the rotation in the canvas as a clock, 0 degrees will be exactly at 3 o'clock, or at the right in relation to your context point. Then, if you rotate 270 degrees, you reach 12 o'clock right above your context point.

In your code, the `moveTo` at the beginning and the first point in the loop are exactly the same (see in demo how Init context point and 0.a are the same). Then, as `rot` is incremented by adding `step`, you see how the points are drawn in order. Moving from outer radius to inner radius.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawStar(cx, cy, spikes, outerRadius, innerRadius) {
    var rot = 270 * Math.PI / 180;
    var x = cx;
    var y = cy;
    var step = Math.PI / spikes;
 
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cx, cy - outerRadius) //100 - 30
    ctx.fillText('Init context point: x: ' + cx + ', y: ' + (cy - outerRadius), cx, cy - outerRadius - 10);

    for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
        $(".display").append(Math.cos(rot) + " , ")
        x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius;
        y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * outerRadius;
        console.log("x : ", x, " y : ", y)
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fillText('(' + i + '.a), ' + rot * (180/Math.PI) + '°', x, y);
        rot += step;

        x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
        y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
        ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
        ctx.fillText('(' + i + '.b), ' + rot * (180/Math.PI) + '°', x, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        rot += step;
    }
    // I've commented this out since closePath() in the next line will do 
    // the same as drawing the last line back to the initial context point.
    // ctx.lineTo(cx, cy - outerRadius);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, 2, 0, (Math.PI * 2), true);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillText("x: " + cx + ', y: ' + cy, cx, cy);
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath();
}

drawStar(150, 150, 5, 100, 50) //cx,cy,spikes, outerRadius, innerRadius
```

```css
canvas{
 background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<div class="display"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what is the measurement of the angel made from (0,a) the red dot and (1,a) in degrees?

Comment: In short, 1.a is 342 degrees from the center. Getting the degrees from radians can be achieved by `degrees = rad * (180/Math.PI)`. I've edited the demo so you can see the degrees of each point based on the radians. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, so the angle will be 342-270 = 72? for angle angle (o,a)x(1,a). or is that not how it works?

Comment: Yes exactly, the angle 0.a, 1.a would be of 72 degrees. But keep in mind that in the canvas, point 0.a is not 0 degrees, but 270. But other than that you get the point.